# Why can the Word file my script created and saved not be opened

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I developed a VBA script in Access that:

1. reads client specific information from my database
2. creates a Word file from a Word template containing this information
3. saves the file in .docx format in a local folder.

Everything works fine on my PC, but an exact copy on my laptop not.
So I have a PC and a laptop with an identical copy of the frontend of the database and the Word template. Both frontends are attached to a backend on a network drive.
The script works fine on the laptop too, however the thus saved file can't be opened (not on my laptop an neither a copy of it on my PC). The content can be read in the explorer preview pane though.
On trying to open the document either:

1. the Word opening screen pops up only shortly and nothing happens
   after that, or
2. Word opens without a document loaded.

My conclusion is, that the saving proces on the laptop corrupts the file.
I can not figure out why?
Both PC and laptop run windows 10 and Office 365).
Here is the code that saves the document:

```
Public Function BestandOpslaan(ByVal Bestandsnaam)
    Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
    
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With fDialog
        .Title = "Sla het bestand op"
        .ButtonName = "Opslaan"
        .InitialFileName = Bestandsnaam
        If .Show <> 0 Then
            BestandOpslaan = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    Set fDialog = Nothing
End Function
```

Has anyone a clue?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that when you transported the Word template file over to the other computer, Word is blocking Access from opening it properly in the first place because of potential internet safety concerns.

On the laptop where this is not working, try opening the Word template file, and if there is a bar across the top warning you that the file is from the internet and that it is currently opened in a restricted mode, click the button to enable all features so that the template will operate normally.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's not the case. The template is not being blocked. It is opened by the script and the edited content is stored in a new file. This new file can be read in the windows explorer preview pane, but cannot be opened as described in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
On the laptop the default-save-as format was set to ".docm"
So the script saved the file with the extention ".docx" as a document with macro's enabled "docm".
Changing this default setting in word (under file | options | save | save files in this format) to ".docx" solved the problem.